# Unknown Encoding/Serialization of Binary Data

Tags: java, flutter, dart, deserialization, decode

So there is this app I used called "War Council" which is used to build Army lists in the ASOIAF mini war game. It has a list export feature which exports a base64 encoded binary blob like so:

`EgVXYXRjaBgFICgoAFoHCIVSELagAVoDCJFSWgMIjFJaAwiRUmCm7gFgse4BYMPtAQ==`

This can then be re-imported to another app on another phone etc..

When I decode this and `xxd` it I see:

```
┌──(admuser㉿wkstation5)-[~]
└─$ xxd decoded2.txt 
00000000: 1209 6a6f 6b69 6e20 6361 7618 0620 2828  ..jokin cav.. ((
00000010: 005a 0708 ac51 10c8 9f01 5a07 08ec 5210  .Z...Q....Z...R.
00000020: c99f 015a 0308 f452 5a03 08ee 5260 90ef  ...Z...RZ...R`..
00000030: 0160 94ef 0160 92ef 01                   .`...`...
```

Here is another one:

`Eglqb2tpbiBjYXYYBiAoKABaBwisURDInwFaBwjsUhDJnwFaAwj0UloDCO5SYJDvAWCU7wFgku8B`

```
┌──(admuser㉿wkstation5)-[~]
└─$ xxd decode.txt 
00000000: 1205 5761 7463 6818 0520 2828 005a 0708  ..Watch.. ((.Z..
00000010: 8552 10b6 a001 5a03 0891 525a 0308 8c52  .R....Z...RZ...R
00000020: 5a03 0891 5260 a6ee 0160 b1ee 0160 c3ed  Z...R`...`...`..
00000030: 01                                       .
```

In the above Watch list, there should be a nights watch spearman unit that has an Id of 10513 in the War Council data. But cant seem to derive that from the data. If it is in fact using the id to store the unit which im inclined to think it is.

I've done a bit of analysis and the App represents all units as integers. I notice that `Watch` and `jokin cav` was the name of the lists I gave them. And it appears to always start with `12` and the `05` or `09` represents the length of the string that follows.

I also tried to decode in dart and java since this was made in the flutter engine which uses dart and compiles into java on android.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
    // Your base64 encoded string
    String base64EncodedString = 'EgVXYXRjaBgFICgoAFoHCIVSELagAVoDCJFSWgMIjFJaAwiRUmCm7gFgse4BYMPtAQ==';

    // Decode the base64 string
    String serializedData = utf8.decode(base64.decode(base64EncodedString));

    try {
        // Try to parse the data as JSON
        dynamic deserializedObject = json.decode(serializedData);

        // Check if the deserialized object is a JSON-like map or an array of integers
        if (deserializedObject is Map) {
            print("Deserialized JSON-like object: $deserializedObject");
        } else if (deserializedObject is List) {
        //} else if (deserializedObject is List && deserializedObject.every((element) => element is int)) {
            print("Deserialized array of integers: $deserializedObject");
        } else {
            print("Deserialized data is of unknown type");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        print("Error during deserialization: $e");
    }
}
```

Java:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Base64Decoder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String base64EncodedString = "EgVXYXRjaBgFICgoAFoHCIVSELagAVoDCJFSWgMIjFJaAwiRUmCm7gFgse4BYMPtAQ==";

        try {
            // Decode the base64 string into bytes
            byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedString);

            // Attempt to deserialize the object
            Object deserializedObject = deserialize(data);
            System.out.println("Deserialized object: " + deserializedObject);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Deserialization failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static Object deserialize(byte[] data) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis)) {
            return in.readObject();
        }
    }
}
```

But no luck, both failed.

Curious if anyone knows what type of encoding/serialization this is and how I can decipher it so I can figure out how to programtically build/import lists into this other product I'm working on.

Here is one more sample:

`EglWaWN0YXJpb24YCCAoKABaAwi4VFoHCLdUEMOiAVoDCLFUWgMItFRaAwiyVGDT8AFg1PABYNXwAQ==`

```
└─$ xxd enc.txt 
00000000: 1209 5669 6374 6172 696f 6e18 0820 2828  ..Victarion.. ((
00000010: 005a 0308 b854 5a07 08b7 5410 c3a2 015a  .Z...TZ...T....Z
00000020: 0308 b154 5a03 08b4 545a 0308 b254 60d3  ...TZ...TZ...T`.
00000030: f001 60d4 f001 60d5 f001                 ..`...`...
```

Comment: The data isn't JSON so trying to use json.decode is useless. You'll need a custom decoder to read this file format. And you'll need the explicit details of the format. You're right it seems to start with (hex) 12, then the number of letters for the name (eg 09), the actual name (Victarion), then your different samples have 18 XX 20 (where XX is 06, 07, or 08, need to determine what this actually is), then 28 28 (two brackets), then some undetermined data, probably the units stats, all ended with 01.

Comment: I figured it would be some kind of known language or package. It seems weird to me they would custom-code their own binary format. This is like 8 units (one army list).

Comment: I doubt it's their own "custom" format—my guess is that those're just the raw, binary data that make up each  `struct Unit` or whatever their language of choice calls it. Given that the name appears plainly after base64 decoding it, I wouldn't be surprised: all three start with `0x12`, which could be a `char flag` or something. Both names are followed the same sequence of bytes, except for the `0x06`, `0x07`, and `0x08`; maybe those are IDs.

Comment: If this is internal data being sent from one instance of the app to another, there's no reason for them to use a custom encoding: just serialize the object into bytes and send them over. Base64 could be being used to allow bundling that binary data up into some text-only format, like JSON.

Comment: It exports it via clipboard/copy paste. So im assuming thats why it uses base64

Comment: Have you tried using `String.fromCharCodes` instead of `utf8.decode`? `String serializedData = String.fromCharCodes(base64.decode(base64EncodedString));`

Comment: Didnt show anything decipherable R¶ RRR`¦î`±î`Ãí

Comment: Have a look at protocol buffers: https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/#simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do any of these look like they match up to what you're expecting

```
2: {"Watch"}
3: 5
4: 40
5: 0
11: {`083f52103f3f01`}
11: {`083f52`}
11: {`083f52`}
11: {`083f52`}
12: 63
`3f01603f3f01603f3f010d0a`


2: {"jokin cav"}
3: 6
4: 40
5: 0
11: {`083f51103f3f01`}
11: {`083f52103f3f01`}
11: {`083f52`}
11: {`083f52`}
12: 63
`3f01603f3f01603f3f010d0a`



2: {"Victarion"}
3: 8
4: 40
5: 0
11: {
  1: 63
  10:EGROUP
}
11: {`083f54103f3f01`}
11: {
  1: 63
  10:EGROUP
}
11: {
  1: 63
  10:EGROUP
}
11: {
  1: 63
  10:EGROUP
}
12: 63
`3f01603f3f01603f3f010d0a`
```

This is your data interpreted as Protcol Buffers (designed by google hence might be plausible for a dart app?)

I did this by (on Windows)

1. putting you base64s into a file
2. running CertUtil (`certutil -decode in.txt out.bin`)
3. running Protoscope (`cat out.bin|protoscope`)
   Protoscope is a go program from [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protoscope)

Does that help?

*EDIT* it looks like a clearer output if you use this app - https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/ - just copy/paste in your base64 strings. I've no idea if the numbers are what you expect but the name parts definitely look right to me.

Comment: This looks promising. Let me get back to you.

Comment: I think this was it! Still confirming but this site seems to have done the trick. Namely:
https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/

I can see the same integers after decoding that represent the integers for each Army unit. 

I'm gonna do a bit more investigating but I think this was the trick.

Comment: Ok, just confirmed this decodes each of the Armies in their entirety. I figured it was some existing encoding/decoding/serialization I just wasn't familiar with.

Comment: Great! Normally with protobufs you'd have a definition file to give meaning to all the fields (e.g. field 2 --> "unit name") but I guess you don't, unless you have the source code for the app. You could always make up your own def based on your understanding of what the fields are.

Comment: Thanks. You've already done so much but based on whats decoded in https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/, do you have an example of what a definition for my examples would look like. Could be totally arbitrary. I was actually trying to figure that out so I could re-encode to get the same basic binary blob/format.

Comment: If it helps, I created a repo of how I decoded this. the resulting json structure is probably not what the app constructs. https://github.com/chrisjd20/war-council-army-decoder/tree/main

No pressure either way. thanks!